# Countdown to a day, updates everyday?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a chrome extension that just has a number and updates everyday( subtracts 1 )

I have already made it print out the number as the chrome extension background but now I am trying to make the number change everyday. **I have 4 files:**

**background.js 

icon_19.png 

jquery.js 

manifest.json**

**icon_19.png**  is needed because in order to set the background of the extension using canvas you must first have a image.

**jquery.js** is just javascript library. I include that.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Countdown",
  "description": "This extension countdowns to my death.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Countdown",
    "default_popup": "countdown.html"
  }
}
```

**background.js:**

```
var today = new Date();
var year = today.getFullYear();
var month = today.getMonth() + 1;
var day = today.getDate();
var myDeath = new Date();
myDeath.setMonth(7);
myDeath.setDate(16);
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 19;
canvas.height = 19;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var start = 18;

ctx.font='20px Arial';

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,19,19);
  ctx.fillText(start, 0, 19, 19);
  start--;
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    imageData: ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19)
  })  
}, 1000);
```

What this does, is it prints out the number(start) as the chrome extension background. Then it begins to count down every 1 second. It works too. I just need to some how make it so that it only subtracts -1 for every next day until I hit `myDeath`. Does anybody know how to  change the number by 1 every day? I want the number to go down once everyday when I open chrome. Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes:

- You'll want to increase the refresh interval. No sense refreshing a day count every second. I've set it at every 12 hours, but you can change it to however many you'd like.
- Calculating the date difference should be its own function, so that you can call it repeatedly. This makes the code a bit easier to maintain, as the death date data is separated from the code that utilizes it.
- I've separated out the death date configuration into its own object for maintainability.
- `death.month` holds a value from 1-12. See the first code comment.
- `death.year` is optional, and that argument is not required in the function.
- Nothing outside of `background.js` needs changing.

#### background.js

```
var death = {
    day: 16,
    month: 8
}
var intervalHours = 12;

function getRemainingDays(d, m, y){
    var today = new Date();
    var myDeath = new Date();
    myDeath.setMonth(m-1); // Month is a range from 0-11; this lets you configure using a range from 1-12
    myDeath.setDate(d);
    if(typeof y !== "undefined"){ // if death.year is not provided, just use the current year
        myDeath.setYear(y);
    }
    return (myDeath-today)/86400000; // (myDeath-today) produces a result in milliseconds, this turns that into days
}

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 19;
canvas.height = 19;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font='20px Arial';

setInterval(function() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,19,19);
  ctx.fillText(getRemainingDays(death.day, death.month), 0, 19, 19);
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
    imageData: ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 19, 19)
  })  
}, (intervalHours*3600000)); // converts hours to milliseconds
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the reply! I noticed one thing though, I think on the ctx.fillText(getRemainingDays(death.day, death.month) wont actually work. Well it doesnt work, but I think its because its trying to draw out the day and the month. When I need to print out the day. I will try to figure it out right now. Just letting you know thats what I think is breaking it.

Comment: Oh! I actually just found the problem! Woo thanks man your code is great! The only problem is the setInterval. It wasnt calling the first number and when I took it out of the setInterval it showed the right number. Now I just have to figure out how to get it to print it out and start the interval.

Comment: Are you even allowed to setInterval in the background for that long in a chrome extension?

Comment: @JoshRobertson Honestly no idea if there's an interval time limit... I was focusing on limiting unnecessary refreshes, and completely failed to consider that the way I wrote it, it wouldn't show the first image until after the interval expired >.< I'm glad you got over that little oversight!